# Calling a redefined method from the base class?

Tags: java, inheritance

This code confuses me a bit

A base class:

```
public class BaseClass {    
    public void g(){
         System.out.print("g in BaseClass\n");
    }

    public void m(){
         System.out.print("m in BaseClass\n");
         g();
    }             
}
```

A class that inherits:

```
public class WhenInheriting extends BaseClass{
    public void g(){
         System.out.print("g in WhenInheriting\n");
         super.g();
    }        
}
```

This is where main is:

```
public class MainIsHere {
    public static void main(String[]args){
           WhenInheriting wi= new WhenInheriting();
           wi.g();
           wi.m();
        }
}
```

results in:

- g in WhenInheriting
- g in BaseClass
- m in BaseClass
- g in WhenInheriting
- g in BaseClass

So, O.K. first `g()` from `WhenInheriting` is called and there through `super.g()` the BaseClass' `g()` is also called.

When `m()` is called, the method `g()` is called from its body. But unlike my expectations that `g()` to be the method from the BaseClass, that `g()` turned out to be the method from the WhenInheriting class.

I can make some logic of this: maybe when `m()` says print that and call `g()`, since the reference knows only one `g()`, that is, the method `g()` from the inheriting class, that one is called.

Now i wanted to know how to write the code so that when `m()` is called from the `WhenInhereting` class the `g()` that will be called through it is the `g()` from the BaseClass?
I tried writing `super.g()` in `m()` instead of only `g()` but that wasn't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what polymorphism is all about. The object's concrete type is `WhenInheriting`, so the polymorphic `g()` method that will be called will always be the `WhenInheriting.g()` method.

This is like real objects. Lets's say you have a Box whose `size()` is 20, and create a BigBox subclass whose `size()` is 40. Let's say I ask you for a box, and you give me the big box. Its `size()` will be 40. Even if I consider this BigBox as a Box and don't even know it's a special Box which is actually a BigBox.

If you want the base class to call a method and make sure that a subclass doesn't override it, then it shouldn't be overridable. So it should call another method `g2()` that is private or final.

Answer (score 0):

The `g()` of `whenInheriting` is being called because methods from a subclass always override methods from a parent class.

If you want `g()` from the parent class called, just instantiate `wi` as an instance of `BaseClass`.